# How to stop the execution of my code in C#?

Tags: c#, terminate, .net-framework-4.8

I have the following code:

```
if (Validar.textbox(Usuario) && Validar.textbox(contrasena))
{
    return;
}  

try
{
   
    Datos.Execute("INSERT INTO `sys_usuarios` VALUES ('','Jesus','','','','','1','')");
}
catch (Exception)
{}

MessageBox.Show(this, "Datos Guardados", "Mensaje",
MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information,
MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
```

Anyway, what I want is that if the condition is met, the code that follows the **IF** is not executed, I want the program to stay until the condition is met. I already tried with Return and it does not stop the execution. I appreciate your help or contribution.

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Selection statements (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements)

Comment: `if (condition) { return; }` is called a guard clause and it will definitely prevent the code below it from being executed. Not sure what you're asking for.